# I tried to press Ctrl D in script and I broke it?

Tags: linux, bash, signals

I write a simple script with an infinite while loop to test something. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    echo -n "Give a number: "; read number
done
```

Then run my script and it was still running, I was pressed Ctrl+D and it broked!
Here is the output:

```
user@DESKTOP:~$ ./test.sh
Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: Give a number: ^C
```

How can I prevent this? Thank you...

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Do you want to exit the loop when Ctrl+D is pressed (this is what a user would normally expect) or do you want to continue reading?

Comment: Yes, I want to exit loop, then echo a message that like '^D is pressed'. Then terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to break out of the loop on read failure:

```
read number || break;
```

When read detects an error, it returns non-zero, which, in the shell, is "false". The `||` will see the false on the left, and thus proceed to evaluate the right, but when the `read` succeeds, returning zero, the `||` will not evaluate the right, allowing the loop to continue.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to solve this problem is:

```
while read -p 'Give a number: ' number; do
   ...
done
```

If the user closes stdin using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then the `read` command exits with non-zero status which causes to loop to exit.
An additional `echo -n` is not necessary; `read` can prompt on its own using the `-p` option.

Comment: I didn't know that way, I am very new at this. Thanks!